# fetch latest tag only

Tags: git, github

I am fetching tags and getting the latest tag value like so:

```
git fetch --tags 
LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --tags $(git rev-list--tags --max-count=1))
```

For the fetch command, is there a way to only fetch the latest tag rather than all tags?

Comment: (Mini typo : missing space after `rev-list`)

Answer (score 2):

List all the tags available from the remote repository.

```
git ls-remote --tags
```

Sort the tags by your rules and find the latest one and fetch it.

```
git fetch origin $tag
```

`git ls-remote` has an option `--sort=<key>`, but it may not work well in your case.